# Waze Deep Link with multiple locations?

Tags: javascript, url, maps, directions, waze

I'm currently making a web app and I want to "share" some addresses to Waze Deep Link to have a turn by turn navigation.

I have tried to use different urls like this but nothing works.

```
https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=40.75889500%2C-73.98513100&ll=41.75889500%2C-75.98513100&navigate=yes&zoom=17
```

I want to know if I can add multiple lat lng points somehow. [Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks/) doesn't say anything about multiple locations. But a couple of weeks ago I saw an app opening waze and showing multiple locations.

How is it possible?

I just tested this link

```
https://www.waze.com/ul?ll=48.70283,-6.13316&navigate=yes&zoom=17&ll=48.71004,6.17222&zoom=17&ll=48.68931,6.1978
```

It has 3 addresses but only takes into account the first and the last one, it ignores complitely the one in the middle